# How do I read a sample from a music file?

Tags: c#, audio, signal-processing

I'm just getting started in music editing from a programming standpoint and I understand a lot of the ideas around waveforms and things of that nature, but I'm stuck on the issue of how to read a single sample from a sound file as an array of bytes.

I'm using the Alvas.Audio library (http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx) and C#, if that helps to answer the question.

I understand that different file formats have different ways of storing the data, but my main problem revolves around how to programmatically determine how that data is stored and iterate through the file one sample at a time.  I will probably be converting all the files to .wav format (using the Alvas library), so an answer specifically for the wav format would suffice, but I'm still curious about iterating samples when the file is in stereo.  From what I understand, files with stereo data store parallel samples consecutively.

My end goal is to be able to get the samples from a certain time period of the song (a few seconds at some place in the song) and then perform some math or other stuff on them, but I'm just never sure that what I have read in is actually the right data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know how to open the file and read data from it, you then need to reference the data file format. For WAV files, see [here](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) for a description on how the data is organised and accessed.

[image]

```
Offset  Size  Name             Description

The canonical WAVE format starts with the RIFF header:

0         4   ChunkID          Contains the letters "RIFF" in ASCII form
                               (0x52494646 big-endian form).
4         4   ChunkSize        36 + SubChunk2Size, or more precisely:
                               4 + (8 + SubChunk1Size) + (8 + SubChunk2Size)
                               This is the size of the rest of the chunk 
                               following this number.  This is the size of the 
                               entire file in bytes minus 8 bytes for the
                               two fields not included in this count:
                               ChunkID and ChunkSize.
8         4   Format           Contains the letters "WAVE"
                               (0x57415645 big-endian form).

The "WAVE" format consists of two subchunks: "fmt " and "data":
The "fmt " subchunk describes the sound data's format:

12        4   Subchunk1ID      Contains the letters "fmt "
                               (0x666d7420 big-endian form).
16        4   Subchunk1Size    16 for PCM.  This is the size of the
                               rest of the Subchunk which follows this number.
20        2   AudioFormat      PCM = 1 (i.e. Linear quantization)
                               Values other than 1 indicate some 
                               form of compression.
22        2   NumChannels      Mono = 1, Stereo = 2, etc.
24        4   SampleRate       8000, 44100, etc.
28        4   ByteRate         == SampleRate * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
32        2   BlockAlign       == NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               The number of bytes for one sample including
                               all channels. I wonder what happens when
                               this number isn't an integer?
34        2   BitsPerSample    8 bits = 8, 16 bits = 16, etc.
          2   ExtraParamSize   if PCM, then doesn't exist
          X   ExtraParams      space for extra parameters

The "data" subchunk contains the size of the data and the actual sound:

36        4   Subchunk2ID      Contains the letters "data"
                               (0x64617461 big-endian form).
40        4   Subchunk2Size    == NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
                               This is the number of bytes in the data.
                               You can also think of this as the size
                               of the read of the subchunk following this 
                               number.
44        *   Data             The actual sound data.
```

**Update:** Added data inline.

Comment: That link was epic, thank you :)

Comment: That link is dead, and a good example of why link-only answers are not helpful.

Comment: Second above thought

Comment: @miken32 updated with content of link

Answer (score 3):

See also [What is a PCM format?](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,articles.aspx#what-is-pcm-format)

PCM (Pulse-code modulation) is an uncompressed audio format. We get the Wav file, that maintains (holds) the PCM data. See how to do What is a Wav-file? Method AudioCompressionManager.GetWaveFormat helps investigate the audio format.

- FormatTag = 1 is PCM.
- Channels = for single-channel (mono), two-channel (stereo), 8 for 7.1 Surround Sound (left, right, center, left surround, right surround, left rear, right rear positions. 7.1 systems also have 1 channel for low frequency effects (LFE) which is usually sent to a subwoofer).
- SamplesPerSec = digitized quantity values per second (or sampling). Could be anything, but the standard values: 8000 Hz, 11025 Hz, 12000 Hz, 16000 Hz, 22050 Hz, 24000 Hz, 32000 Hz, 44100 Hz, 48000 Hz.
- BitsPerSample - most common uses 8 bits (1 byte) and 16 bits (2 bytes). Rarely 24 bits (3 bytes), 32 bits (4 bytes) and 64 bits (4 bytes). If we consider the 16 bit as a basic, then 8 bits can be considered as a compressed format. It has two times less size, but the variants of values can be only 28 = 256 instead of 216 = 65536 for 16 bits. That's why, 8 bits sound quality will be significantly lower than 16 bits.
- BlockAlign = Channels * BitsPerSample / 8. Where 8 is the quantity of bits per byte.
- AvgBytesPerSec (bitrate) = Channels * SamplesPerSec * BitsPerSample / 8.

You can use the code below to analyze PCM audio format in more particularly.

```
    private void WhatIsPcmFormat(string fileName)
    {
        WaveReader wr = new WaveReader(File.OpenRead(fileName));
        IntPtr format = wr.ReadFormat();
        wr.Close();
        WaveFormat wf = AudioCompressionManager.GetWaveFormat(format);
        if (wf.wFormatTag == AudioCompressionManager.PcmFormatTag)
        {
            int bitsPerByte = 8;
            Console.WriteLine("Channels: {0}, SamplesPerSec: {1}, BitsPerSample: {2}, BlockAlignIsEqual: {3}, BytesPerSecIsEqual: {4}", 
            wf.nChannels, wf.nSamplesPerSec, wf.wBitsPerSample, 
            (wf.nChannels * wf.wBitsPerSample) / bitsPerByte == wf.nBlockAlign, 
            (int)(wf.nChannels * wf.nSamplesPerSec * wf.wBitsPerSample) / bitsPerByte == wf.nAvgBytesPerSec);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most common way of 'packing' audio data is PCM - used in uncompressed WAV files.  Each sample is 'packed' into short integer values (`short`) and if you have library that can give PCM, you can get your data by treating them as a array of `short` values.

Depending on the number of channels, you'll have that amount of `short`s per sample.  As each `short` is 2 `byte`s, you usually have 4 bytes per sample for stereo audio.

So for example to access audio data at 1.0s position into the audio file, you have to skip 44100*4 bytes, assuming that audio is sampled at 44100 (most common sampling rate - comes from CDs).